# After dismissing the alert appium is no longer detecting any element on the screen

Tags: appium, android-7.0-nougat

Basically everything works until a notification is displayed on screen. After i dismiss the alert i, appium is no longer detecting any of my buttons, fields, etc. The only things that works is if i put the app in background and resume it. After resume everything works. (i`m using Appium 1.6.4, with Android 7.0).

Any hint here?

Comment: Can you dismiss the alert by using xpath/locators without using switch to alert and try

Comment: I am clicking on allow button of permission pop up using xpath only. I am not using any switch to ()

Comment: Did you get the same with switchto and check

Comment: We cant use it as appium is returning java.lang.AssertionError: Not yet implemented. error while using  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Answer (score 2):

It is [known issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7806) in appium project.

Workaround that I use:

- get coordinates (x, y) of any element on screen before opening dialog
- interact with dialog (e.g. select elements, close etc.)
- tap by coordinates (x, y) after closing dialog:

`new TouchAction(driver).tap(x, y).perform();`

Only after clicking on screen by coordinates it will find elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround for this problem is -  you can put app in background and launch again.

driver.runAppInBackground(5);

Comment: It worked for me. Appium 1.6.5 & Android 7.1.1. It auto-launches again. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work with any secure production app, because the manifest should be set to not allow third-party activities to start a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution for this if you don't want to click on the permission pop ups. Before you launch/initialise the appium driver, just give all the required permissions to the respective app through adb command as below so that the **ALLOW** pop up won't be displayed:

```
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.CAMERA
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
        adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinod For permission poput this solution is fine, But appium stop identifying element even after normal popup e.g. Are you sure you want to cancel this ? cancel and confirm for normal android popups.

Comment: This is strange. We have scripts in which we click on different type of pop ups including OS and app pop ups, but appium keeps working after that as well.

Comment: What is your device os version and Appium version .. are you using java or c#

Comment: Android 6.0 , Appium 1.6.4 and Java 8

Comment: Till android 6 it is working fine as i mentioned in question problem starts with Android 7.0